# How do I add many CSV files to the catalog in Kedro?

Tags: python, kedro

I have hundreds of CSV files that I want to process similarly. For simplicity, we can assume that they are all in `./data/01_raw/` (like `./data/01_raw/1.csv`, `./data/02_raw/2.csv`) etc. I would much rather not give each file a different name and keep track of them individually when building my pipeline. I would like to know if there is any way to read all of them in bulk by specifying something in the `catalog.yml` file?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are looking for [PartitionedDataSet](https://kedro.readthedocs.io/en/stable/05_data/02_kedro_io.html#partitioned-dataset). In your example, the `catalog.yml` might look like this:

```
my_partitioned_dataset:
  type: "PartitionedDataSet"
  path: "data/01_raw"
  dataset: "pandas.CSVDataSet"
```