# How do I add multiple csv files to the catalog in kedro

Tags: azure-blob-storage, kedro

I have 4 csv files in Azure blob storage, with same metadata, that i want to process. How can i add them to the datacatalog with a single name in Kedro.
I checked this question
`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61645397/how-do-i-add-many-csv-files-to-the-catalog-in-kedro`
But this seems to load all the files in the given folder.
But my requirement is to read only given 4 from many files in the azure container.

Example:
I have many files in azure container in which are  4 transaction csv files with names sales_<date_from>_<date_to>.csv, i want to load  these 4 transaction csv files into kedro datacatalog under one dataset.

Comment: A concrete example would be very helpful so that we can help work towards a solution. Right now, have to make assumptions around what your structure may look like.

Comment: Example added hope this will help you understand.

Answer (score 1):

For starters, `PartitionedDataSet` is lazy, meaning that files are not actually loaded until you explicitly call that function. Even if you have 100 CSV files that get picked up by the `PartitionedDataSet`, you can select the partitions that you actually load/work with.

Second, what distinguishes these 4 files from the others? If they have a unique suffix, you can use the `filename_suffix` option to just select them. For example, if you have:

```
file_i_dont_care_about.csv
first_file_i_care_about.csv
second_file_i_care_about.csv
third_file_i_care_about.csv
fourth_file_i_care_about.csv
```

you can specify `filepath_suffix: _file_i_care_about.csv`.

Comment: I have files like `sales_<date_from>_<date_to>.csv`
may be i have to rename the files like `<date_from>_<date_to>_sales.csv`
to use filename_suffix option

Answer (score 0):

Don’t think there’s a direct way to do this , you can add another subdirectory inside the blob storage with the 4 files and then use

`my_partitioned_dataset:`

`type:` "PartitionedDataSet"

`path:` "data/01_raw/subdirectory/"

`dataset:` "pandas.CSVDataSet"

Or in case the requirement of using only 4 files is not going to change anytime soon ,you might as well pass 4 files in the `catalog.yml` separately to avoid over engineering it.